# Submitting a PHP form to store data as XML in a file

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have set up this form with the intention of when I add details into the; title, description and emotion text fields and then press submit, this data will be stored as xml in the php file.

I am struggling to set up the controller so that when I submit the form it actually stores this data. The example that I will provide below worked previously when I was storing it on my database, but I am now wanting to store it as xml.

> Projects Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;

interface OutputType
{
public function generate();
}

//project class has been imported
use App\Project;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    //because the class has been imported we can reference it like this rather than '\App\Project::all();'
    $projects = Project::all();



//passing the JSON to the view

    return view ('projects.index', ['projects'=> $projects]); //can also use 'compact('projects') instead of the ['projects'=> $projects]
 }



//new method called create

public function create()
{

    return view ('projects.create');

}

//new method called store


public function store()
 {

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $xmlType = new XMLType();
    $xmlType->createParent('programme', ['id' => 1])
            ->addElement('name', $_POST['name'], ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addElement('description', $_POST['description'])
            ->addElement('mood', $_POST['mood'])
            ->groupParentAndElements()
            ->createParent('others', ['id' => 2, 'attr' => 'ex'])
            ->addElement('example', 'A value here')
            ->groupParentAndElements();

    //whenever you wish to output
    $xmlType->generate();
 }



return view('projects.upload');
}


//changed this from upload to show
public function upload()
{


return view('projects.upload');
}

//changed this from upload to show
public function show()
{


return view ('projects.upload', compact('user'));
}

public function slider()
{


return view ('projects.upload', compact('user'));
}


}
```

> Database.php (where I want to store submitted data as xml

```
<?
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programmeList>
<programme id="1">
 <name>School of Rock</name>
 <image>images/schoolofrock.jpg</image>
 <description>After being kicked out of a rock band, Dewey Finn becomes a substitute teacher </description>
 <mood>Agitated</mood>
 </programme>
<programme id="2">
<name>Pitch Perfect 2</name>
<image>images/pitchperfect2.jpg</image>
<description>After a humiliating command performance at The Kennedy       Center, the Barden Bellas enter an international competition that no American group has ever won in order to regain their status and right to perform.</description>
 <mood>Fearless</mood>
 </programme>
</programmeList>
XML;
?>
```

> Create.php (view)

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/app.css" type="text/css">
 <meta name = "viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://www.w3schools.com. /lib/w3.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Sky logo + Sky cinema logo -->
<div class="box">
  <td style="text-align:center;color:black;font-size:50px;">
     <img src="/images/sky.png"  title="Sky" alt="Sky" width="auto" height="125" />
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: right;position: relative; color:black;font-size:50px;">
     <img src="/images/sky_cinema.png"  title="sky_cinema" alt="Sky" width="auto" height="125" />
   </td>
</div>

<div>
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
<li><a href="/projects/upload">Moodslider Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/projects/create">Upload Content</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
     <h1>Upload a movie</h1>
</div>
<!--post request followed by an action which states where the data will be posted/returned -->

 <form method="POST" action="/projects">


 <form action="/projects/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {{ @csrf_field() }}
 <h4>Movie Title</h4><input type="text" name="name">
  <br/>
 <h4>Movie Description</h4><textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="50" wrap="physical">
 </textarea>
 <h4>Movie Emotion</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Agitated">Agitated<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Calm">Calm<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Happy">Happy<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Sad">Sad<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Tired">Tired<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="WideAwake">Wide Awake<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Scared">Scared<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mood" value="Fearless">Fearless<br>
  <br/>
  Choose a file to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> XMLType

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//import the interface above

class XMLType implements OutputType
{
    protected $xml;
    protected $parentElement;
    protected $elementGroup;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->xml= new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-15');
    }

    public function createParent($type, $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->parentElement = $this->xml->createElement($type);
        $this->addAttributes($this->parentElement, $attributes);
        return $this;
    }

    private function addAttributes(&$element, $attributes)
    {
        if (sizeof($attributes) > 0) {
            foreach($attributes as $type => $value) {
                $element->setAttribute($type, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addElement($type, $element, $attributes = [])
    {
         $this->elementGroup = $this->xml->createElement($type, $element);
         $this->addAttributes($this->elementGroup, $attributes);
         return $this;
    }

    public function groupParentAndElements()
    {
        $this->parentElement->appendChild($this->elementGroup);
        return $this;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $this->xml->appendChild($this->parentElement);
        print $this->xml->saveXML(); //here I am saving and printing but you can change to suit your needs. It is at this point it is ready to generate the XML
    } 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using SQLite to store the data as a second DB connection

https://www.sqlite.org

Alternatively you would need to use something like SimpleXML grab the contents of the file, add or modify the contents and then save it back to the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

This would all need to go in your store method and would not allow you to use the Projects model

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Interface**

```
        interface OutputType
        {
            public function generate();
        }
```

**XMLFile Class**

```
            //import the interface above

        class XMLType implements OutputType
        {
            protected $xml;

            protected $parentElement;
            protected $elementGroup;


            protected $parentList = [];
            protected $elementList = [];

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->xml= new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-15');
            }

            public function createParent($type, $attributes = [])
            {
                $this->parentElement = $this->xml->createElement($type);
                $this->addAttributes($this->parentElement, $attributes);

                return $this;
            }

            private function addAttributes(&$element, $attributes)
            {
                if (sizeof($attributes) > 0) {
                    foreach($attributes as $type => $value) {
                        $element->setAttribute($type, $value);
                    }
                }
            }

            public function addElement($type, $element, $attributes = [])
            {
                 $this->elementGroup  = $this->xml->createElement($type, $element);
                 $this->addAttributes($this->elementGroup, $attributes);
                 $this->elementList[] = $this->elementGroup;
                 return $this;
            }

            /**
             *  We wish to trigger this every time you want to ad d a new parent to
             *  hold new elements! So the program knows to close
             *  the previous one before starting a new and mesh all into one single
             *  element, which we do not want to!
            **/
            public function groupParentAndElements()
            {
                foreach($this->elementList as $prevElements) {
                    $this->parentElement->appendChild($prevElements);
                }

                $this->parentList[] = $this->parentElement;
                $this->elementList = [];

                return $this;
            }

            public function generate()
            {
                //Uses filled parentList where each parent contains its child elements to generate the XML
                foreach ($this->parentList as $prevParent) {
                    $this->xml->appendChild($prevParent);    
                }

                //here I am saving and printing but you can change to suit your needs.
                //It is at this point it is ready to generate the XML
                print $this->xml->saveXML(); 
            } 

        }
```

**Where you wish to use the XML class**

```
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $xmlType = new XMLType();
                $xmlType->createParent('programme', ['id' => 1])
                        ->addElement('name', $_POST['name'], ['type' => 'string'])
                        ->addElement('description', $_POST['description'])
                        ->addElement('mood', $_POST['mood'])
                        ->groupParentAndElements()
                        ->createParent('others', ['id' => 2, 'attr' => 'ex'])
                        ->addElement('example', 'A value here')
                        ->groupParentAndElements();

                //whenever you wish to output
                $xmlType->generate();
            }
```

**Output**

```
            <programme id="1">
                <name type="string">
                    //your post name
                </name>
                <description>
                    //your post description
                </description>
                <mood>
                    //your post mood
                </mood>
            </programme>
            <others id="2" attr="ex">
               <example>
                   A value here
               </example>
            </others>
```

To the class you can always add extra elements like notes, types etc, it will be up to your XML needs. Just need to follow the structure or even go further :)

[working code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bf303b4cf60c991f083dcddbd747c68305f2289)

**Storing the XML content into a file**

```
interface FileCreationContract
{
    public function create($content);
}


class XMLFile implements FileCreationContract
{

    const REGEX_EXTENTION_LOOKOUT = '/\.[^.]+$/';
    const EXTENTION = '.xml';

    protected $path;
    protected $filename;

    public function __construct ($filename, $path = '')
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->parseFilename();

        if (empty($this->path)) {
            $this->path = realpath(__DIR__);
        }
    }

    /**
     * If programmer mistakes and adds extention, removes it to make sure the wrong extention was not added;
     */
    private function parseFilename()
    {
        if ( strpos($this->filename, self::EXTENTION) === FALSE ) {
            $this->filename = preg_replace(self::REGEX_EXTENTION_LOOKOUT, '', $this->filename) . self::EXTENTION;
        }

        if (empty($this->filename)) {
            $this->filename = 'default-name'.self::EXTENTION;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPath ()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $path
     *
     * @return XMLFile
     */
    public function setPath ($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFilename ()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $filename
     *
     * @return XMLFile
     */
    public function setFilename ($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->parseFilename();
        return $this;
    }

    public function create ($content)
    {
        $file = fopen($this->path.$this->filename, 'w') or die("Unable too open file!"); //I recommend throwing an exception here!
        fwrite($file, $content);
        fclose($file);
    }

}
```

**At your controller, after constructing the XML Content**

```
...
$xmlFile = new XMLFile('database.php', 'path/to/your/public/folder/');
$xmlFile->create($xmlType->generate());
...
```

**NOTE:** Replace `print` to `return` on your `generate()` method from `XMLType` class

This new class wil make sure your filename follows the expected `.xml` format for saving. You can always override the path to save the file at constructor level or call `->setPath('new/path/');` to replace it, before you call `create()`;

Comment: Hi, where within this would I state which file the data should be stored within?

Comment: Hey @Matthew! No, I would leave the XMLType class to only be responsible to originate the XML and put the responsability on where to save (if DB, curl it or save it to a file) outside of the class. You can either create a second class to handle that or add it after you use the `generate() method` to return the output and then save it to a file

Comment: This because we should look for a `single responsibility` when handling code, specially `classes` so we do not want our class to be responsible to `generate XML` and `save to a specific location`

Comment: I just noticed you wish `id`  to be present. I will adapt the code to consider those

Comment: Added the new code and refactored one problem I noticed when using the $_POST variables. Should be okay now! :)

Comment: getting an 'invalid character error' message thrown now, highlighting this part of the code 'public function addElement($element, $type, $attributes = [])
        {
             $this->elementGroup = $this->xml->createElement($type, $element);
             $this->addAttributes($this->elementGroup, $attributes);
             return $this;
        }'

Comment: Hmm checking this atm

Comment: Would it be easier if I added the code into the question so that you can see if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Think it is fixed @Matthew! I confused the `$type` and $element` order in that method in question. I also noticed i forgot to add `$this->xml` in the `generate()` method, so I call to your attention you  will need to fix that as well in case you copied the code.

Comment: @Matthew you can add the code so I can also double check the intention :)

Comment: Lastly, with code being set up correctly on my part, can you please give an example of how I can store the XML into a file :) This has been such a massive help, thanks

Comment: @Matthew I am going through it right now and doing some changes to better automate the process and reduce the things you have to call on your controller as well! Bear with me will be done in a few minutes :)

Comment: @Matthew many apologies, I noticed a problem when generating more than 1 parent. It is now fixed! Please refer to the example link I post in the answer to also confirm the output and functionality of the code :)

Comment: Yes, this now returns the data. How do I get it to store the the results within a file? I am wanting to store the results in a Database.php file

Comment: Alright let me show you by adding that to the example :) may I ask why you desire to do so in `database.php` instead of a `programs.xml`?

Comment: apologies, it is is a database.xml file

Comment: the xml file is stored in my public folder too

Comment: @Matthew added the new file to handle your file creation. Let me know how it went

Comment: Hi Diogo, I have created the new class and added the code along with editing the existing XMLType generate methods code. This compiles fine however it doesn't appear to be storing the data in the xml file. Also, if i leave the print method in the code, the data that I input is coming out twice.

Comment: You have to **remove the print** from `generate()` you want to **return only**.
As for the file creation, make sure your path is correct, so would advice to call  `getPath()` and `getFilename()` from the class to double check all is fine.